# I want to make this kind of batch file, it will work?

Tags: file, batch-file, if-statement

I want to make this kind of batch file

```
       @ECHO OFF
(
    IF  "pulsar.exe" exist (
    taskkill /f /im "pulsar.exe" 
    )
    ELSE (
    run "C:\Program Files (x86)\XBMC\XBMC.exe" 
     )
 )
```

i want the XBMC will run the scipt auto

Comment: so what is the question?

Comment: OK. Go ahead. It's fine with me.

Comment: `if exist ...` , though i don't know why you would want to kill it depending on the existence of a file on disk.

Comment: the code is fine ???
 'cuz i'm want it run as ascript

Comment: And THS, when i exit the xbmc , the pulsar is still working and make a bug

Comment: you check, if the file exists, but I'm sure, you want to know, if the process is running. Use `tasklist |find /i "pulsar.exe"` for that. (if it doesn't work, see `tasklist /?` or come back here wtih your code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
IF  exist "pulsar.exe" (
 taskkill /f /im "pulsar.exe" 
) ELSE (
  "C:\Program Files (x86)\XBMC\XBMC.exe" 
)
```

This is a syntactically-valid version of your code.

You don't say what problem you are attempting to solve, so the comments you've received are correct.

This routine checks for the existence of the file `"pulsar.exe"` (note: `if exist filename`)

If the file exists, then kill the pulsar.exe task.

If the file does not exist, then execute `xbmc.exe`

Note that the positioning of the parentheses is critical. The overall set of `()` surrounding the entire procedure is not required. That structure may be used to redirect output from the procedure to a file - but you're not apparently outputting anything.

The `if` and its matching `(` must be on the same physical line (you had that OK).

If used, the `else and its matching`(` must be on the same physical line (you had that OK).

If used, the `)` to close the `if` and the `else` must be on the same physical line.

Each `(` taking part in the `if...else` must be preceded by a space and each `)` taking part must be succeeded by a space or newline.

All you need to invoke an executable is to use its name. If the executable is a batch file, you need to `call executablename parameters` otherwise control is *transferred* to the batch invoked.

Batch will wait until a .exe is terminated before proceeding. You can use `start "windowtitle" executablename parameters` to create an independent process and continue with the batch. `"windowtitle"` is nominally optional, but best included - even left empty (ie `""`) to avoid confusing `cmd`.

Answer (score 0):

I did that

```
        @ECHO OFF
IF exist "pulsar.exe" == tasklist /fi "imagename eq pulsar.exe"
( taskkill /f /im "pulsar.exe" 
) 
 If not exist "pulsar.exe" == tasklist /fi "imagename eq pulsar.exe"
 ("C:\Program Files (x86)\XBMC\XBMC.exe" 
 )
```